# Basis for Rational Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, rational-functions

Suppose $F$ is a field, and let $F(x)$ denote the $F$-vector space of all rational functions $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, where $f,g\in F[x]$ are polynomials, with $g$ different from zero. Let $F(x)_p$ denote the subspace of F(x) of all proper fractions, i.e. all $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where degree($f$) $<$ degree($g$). It is know that

$$\beta= \{\frac{x^{j}}{p(x)^{k}} \mid p(x) \text{is a monic irreducible polynomial}, 0\leq j< \text{degree}(p); k\geq 1 \}$$

> is a basis for $F(x)_p$ as an $F$-vector space. 
>   What other basis that could be constructed for F(x)? I mean is there any other basis for F(x)?

Can anyone help me please? or provide me a reference about basis specially if F is finite.

Comment: $F$ being finite here doesn't help much. You can always apply any basis transformation to obtain a new basis.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please explain more?

Comment: Say you have a basis $e_1,e_2,e_3,\dots$, you can take e.g. $e_1,\ e_1+e_2,\ e_1+e_2+e_3,\ \dots$